# How to use Amazon Corretto JDK with Github Actions?

Tags: github-actions, corretto

I have a Github Java project that uses Amazon Corretto 11.

But I am not able to write a Github action so that workflow would build the project at every pull request.

For example, with OpenJDK it would look like below

```
# This workflow will build a Java project with Maven
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/building-and-testing-java-with-maven

name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'adopt'
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
```

How to use Corretto instead of OpenJDK? Is there a Github standard action to do that? Or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use that action you would probably need to submit a PR to the action to add Coretto as a supported distribution.

I am curious why it matters though? You should be able to build using any Java distribution. Is there a reason you think you need to build using Correto?

Comment: Excerpt from Amazon's corretto release blog :
`We downstream fixes made in OpenJDK, add enhancements based on our own experience and needs, and then produce Corretto builds. In case any upstreaming efforts for such patches is not successful, delayed, or not appropriate for OpenJDK project, we will provide them to our customers for as long as they add value. If an issue is solved a different way in OpenJDK, we will move to that solution as soon as it is safe to do so. `

which means there will be differences(though minor) between the two.. Correct me if my understanding is misplaced.

Comment: On the same lines: are you suggesting that differences between these two will only affect runtime while code compilation and build would be unaffected?

Comment: I have used Corretto too, but I would generally expect the output of compiled Java code to be the same regardless of which version of OpenJDK you build with. I guess in theory they could downstream a compiler fix but it seems unlikely and not worth concerning yourself with.

Comment: https://github.com/actions/setup-java/issues/68